# onclick submit Button: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null

Tags: javascript, html

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null
    at register (VM43 js.js:66)
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick ((index):18)
```

Name should be null but it isnt. Somebody any ideas how i could fix this? Im new to html/js

```
<form>
  <input name="Name" type ="text" value="Name">
  <input name="Description" type="text" value="Description">
    <select name="Art" size="3">
      <option value="photo">Photo</option>
      <option value="video">Video</option>
    <input type="datetime-local" name="DateTime">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="Upload" onclick="register();">
</form>
```

JS:

```
function register(){
  var name = document.getElementById('Name').value;//document.getElementsByTagName("firstname")[0].firstChild.data;
  var desc = document.getElementById('Description').value;
  var date = document.getElementById('DateTime').value;
  request.open("post", "db.php", false);
  request.onreadystatechange = scoreBoard;
  request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  //request.send("INSERT INTO Accounts VALUES('3', 'fl', 'pass')");
  console.log("f:"+f+" l:"+l+" e:"+e+" p:"+p);
  request.send("INSERT INTO `Uplouds`(name, descr, date) VALUES('"+name+"', '"+desc+"', '"+date+"')");
}
```

Thanks a lot
Felix

Comment: Where's the JS code?

Comment: You need to show the code for `register()`.

Comment: i edidited my Question above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `IDs` to your elements to be able to use the function `getElementById`:

That's why you're getting `null` because there aren't any elements with these IDs: `Name`, `Description` and `Datetime`.

```
<form>
  <input id="Name" name="Name" type ="text" value="Name">
  <input id="Description" name="Description" type="text" value="Description">
    <select id="Art" name="Art" size="3">
      <option value="photo">Photo</option>
      <option value="video">Video</option>
    <input type="datetime-local" name="DateTime" id="DateTime">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="Upload" onclick="register();">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot this fixed it